# CV_8UC1 to CV_32FC1 conversion in OpenCV

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing

the way we convert the image type from `CV_8UC1` to `CV_32FC1` in OpenCV with C++ API is

```
        r1.convertTo(r1, CV_32FC1, 1.0/255.0);
```

where `r1` is the matrix declared as `cv::Mat`. 
Can anybody tell me how to convert from `CV_8UC1` to `CV_32FC1` type in OpenCV with C API? If `r2` is a matrix described as `CvMat* r2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[cvConvertScale()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#void%20cvConvertScale%28const%20CvArr*%20src,%20CvArr*%20dst,%20double%20scale,%20double%20shift%29) can do what you want.

Assuming you have a cvMat* r1 of type 8UC1 and a cvMat* r2 of type 32FC1 and of the same size then

```
cvConvertScale(r1, r2, 1.0 / 255.0, 0.0);
```

Since the destination type is taken from r2, it cannot be the same cvMat as r1.

Comment: Crashes i my code. The documentation tells, it is the old-style C function for converting CvArr types: **C: void cvConvertScale(const CvArr* src, CvArr* dst, double scale=1, double shift=0)**. Is it appropriate also for cv::Mat?

Comment: No, `cvConvertScale()` is not appropriate for a cv::Mat. The question actually says what to do for a cv::Mat.