# convert cv::Mat to Cvmat* in OpenCV

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing

Suppose, I am declaring my CvMat* as shown below and then converting it to cv::Mat and then doing the conversion of types from `CV_8UC1` to `CV_32FC1`. Then after the conversion, I want to revert it back to CVMat*. Can anbody tell me how can I do the conversion from cv::Mat to CvMat* ?

```
     CvMat* r1 = cvLoadImageM(argv[2], 0);
     cv::Mat r1cpp(r1);
     r1.convertTo(r1, CV_32FC1, 1.0/255.0);
```

Or does anybody knows how can I do the conversion of `CV_8UC1` to `CV_32FC1` with C API?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CV\_8UC1 to CV\_32FC1 conversion in OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745845/cv-8uc1-to-cv-32fc1-conversion-in-opencv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert CV_8UC1 to CV_32FC1 with C API using [`cvConvertScale((src), (dst), 1, 0 )`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html#convertscale) command as follows

```
// source image
CvMat* src = cvLoadImageM(argv[2], 0); 

// allocate destination image of type CV_32F
CvMat* dst = cvCreateMat(src->height, src->width, CV_32FC1) 

// convert src image to dst image (type CV_32F)
cvConvertScale(src, dst, 1, 0 );
```

Comment: Another method which I found out is 

         CvMat*  r3 = cvCreateMat(rgbMat->height, rgbMat->width, CV_32FC1); 
         cvConvert(r1, r3);